# Generate a random birthday given an age

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime, random

I'm looking for a good algorithm, preferably using the CLR's `DateTime` type and other built-in stuff, versus just using on-the-metal maths, for guessing a birthday date given an age.

The date should be realistic looking, and not just always 1st of January. I need them for testing an app where a number containing the birthday digits is validated with a Luhn check-digit.

What I have so far is to subtract the age from now, giving me a minimum date. Then I can randomize years, months, and days to add. Yet that latter process is rough in terms of getting the wrong random month or day could change the eventual age for the date.

Comment: Can you post come code?  What have you tried?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *"guessing"*. Also, you should add to the question what you have already tried, and it would be useful to see what input you need and what output do you expect.

Comment: @Kyle I would have, but I asked this question at work, and I only have source at home.

Comment: Do you want to randomly generate a date between a min and max?  Do you want to generate all the dates between a min and max?  It's really not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I mean using randomizing to generate a birthday, and only accepting the birthday if the age it would give its owner is within my limits. I thought I made my input and output quite clear: I will supply a min and or max age, a number of birthdays, and I expect as output a range of birthdays that place a person in the given age range.

Comment: No, @juharr, I want to randomly generate a date that would put a person between a min and a max age. It's a small but super important difference.

Comment: @ProfK So are you just stuck on the age to date conversion part or how to create a random date within a range?

Comment: You are saying the exact same thing as @juharr, only phrasing it differently. You want to generate a date between a min and a max. The min and max would be calculated based on the current date minus the oldest and youngest age in your range.

Comment: @ProfK take a look at this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qoTqkj). Question got closed before I could submit.

Comment: Thanks, @Nkosi. I've flagged it for moderation, so hear's hoping you get another chance.

Comment: @ProfK provide a [mcve] of what you have tried so far. That way the question can be on topic. You stated that you had a current candidate for the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

A quick-and-dirty solution that finds a date between `min` and `max` using `Ticks`:

```
var min = DateTime.Parse("1988/02/10");
var max = DateTime.Parse("2016/01/05");

var minTicks = min.Ticks;
var maxTicks = max.Ticks;

var baseTicks = maxTicks-minTicks;

var rnd = new Random();

var toAdd = (long)(rnd.NextDouble()*baseTicks);

var newDate = new DateTime(minTicks+toAdd);
```

Of course if you need multiple dates you may add them to a list:

```
public static List<DateTime> GetBirthdaysBetweenDates(DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate, int number = 1)
{
    if(minDate > maxDate) throw new ArgumentException("minDate can't be greater then maxDate");

    var dates = new List<DateTime>();

    if(number <= 0) return dates;

    var rnd = new Random();

    var ticks = maxDate.Ticks - minDate.Ticks;

    for(var i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        var toAdd = (long)(rnd.NextDouble() * ticks);
        dates.Add(new DateTime(minDate.Ticks + toAdd));
    }

    return dates;
}
```

Comment: One point scored for using ticks. I was thinking long similar lines myself.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with something like this:

```
//define lowest and highest days here
DateTime dateFrom = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);
DateTime dateTo = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1);
//calculate number of days
int daysRange = dateTo.Subtract(dateFrom).Days;

//list to hold generated birthdays
List<DateTime> birthdays = new List<DateTime>();

//randomizer
Random rand = new Random();
//number of birthdays to generate
int number = 10;
for (int i = 0; i<number; i++)
{
    //genrate number between 0 and daysRange and add that many days to dateFrom
    DateTime newDate = dateFrom.AddDays(rand.Next(daysRange));
    //add to list
    birthdays.Add(newDate);
}
```

Comment: Now looks a lot like what I'm looking for. Thanks! If it works nicely, you will have to wait until I can place a bounty before I accept, because you sure deserve one for a) understanding the simple enough question, b) not berating me if you can't understand such a simple requirement.

Comment: @ProfK lol glad I could help. I think the question is clear enough, but the community downvoted and flagged it because it lacks your attempt at coding something

Comment: the community be damned in that case. I thought it through extremely well - I don't always need code to attack a coding problem, just because they need it because they can't grok narrative. Anyway, I've now decried my current candidate for the algorithm.

Comment: @ProfK take a look at this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qoTqkj) similar to the above but refactored to accept age range.